# How do you search for a specific date in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, format, date-time

Whenever I search for a date in excel using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, it never works. I've tried searching for a date using the displayed format, ie. `2020-12-31` and even though I can see the date in the column, excel says it can't find any matching values. I've also tried searching for the underlying integer value that represents the date and excel still can't find it.

What I want to do is find any dates that have the value `1900-01-01`, but I get erratic behavior from excel. For example if I search for the value `0` it tells me it found a match from the date with integer value `44104` which represents the date `2020-09-30`.

So is it possible to search for a specific date in excel, or is it's search totally borked?

Answer (score 2):

Search for the exact date (as it is displayed).

In order to do that, expand the *Options* on the Search dialog, and select *Search in: Values*

If the date is a fixed value rather than the result of a formula, you can search in either *Formulas* or *Values*.

[image: Search date by value]

Answer (score 1):

This is a formula execution to find dates in a certain cell range,

```
IF(COUNTIFS(C8:C21, 12/2/2015), "YES", "NO")
```

I referred this method from [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/range-contains-specific-date).

I tried Xlookup & vlookup, strangely they are not this simple in finding specific dates.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find cells containing specific date using the find & select function at the editing tab of the ribbon go to options and select values in the lookin: dropdown list

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).